# Add an item in a container of smart pointers

Tags: c++, containers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Several ways to add an item in a container of smart pointers. I am wondering which way you will go for.

```
class MyContainer
{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> mItems;

public:
    bool Add(Item* item);
    // This is Way 1
    //
    // Advantages: 
    // - Easy to add derived items, such as Add(new DerivedItem);
    // - No interface change if smart pointer type changes to such as shared_ptr;
    //
    // Disadvantages:
    // - Don't explicitly show the item to add must be allocated on heap;
    // - If failed to add, user has to delete the item.

    bool Add(std::unique_ptr<Item> item);
    // This is Way 2
    // Disadvantages and advantages are reversed from Way 1.
    // Such as to add derived item, Add(std::unique_ptr<Item>(new DerivedItem));
    //                                                    |
    //                               easy to write DerivedItem here for an error

    bool Add(std::unique_ptr<Item>& item);
    // This is Way 3
    // Similar to Way 2, but when failed to add, item still exist if it is a 
    // reference of outer unique_ptr<Item>

};
```

I personally go for Way 1. Any more advantages for Way 2 and 3 or disadvantages of Way 1 that I should go for 2 or 3?

sftrabbit gives many good points. In the following common case. How to use Way 2 or 3 to do it easily? User uses a dialog to generate a new derived item. It is put on `std::unique_ptr<DerivedItem> item`. When click 'OK' button, it is added to the container. If failed to add, go back to the dialog for an edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I vote for:

```
bool Add(std::unique_ptr<Item> item);
```

Reasons:

1. It's clear from the function signature that the client needs to pass ownership of the object to the `MyContainer`. If you choose option 1 instead, it's still not clear if the client should `delete` the object themselves or not, or even if they should be passing a dynamically allocated object.
2. Client is forced to explicitly transfer ownership with `std::move` if they already have the object managed by a named `std::unique_ptr`. They won't accidentally lose ownership. Option 3 does not clearly express that it's going to take ownership.
3. When we have [`std::make_unique` (N3588)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3588.htm), the method for adding an element will be:

   ```
   container.Add(std::make_unique<Item>());
   ```

   This avoids using `new` and improves exception safety in some situations.
4. The issue you've given for derived objects is not really a problem. You'll get a compile-time error if you do it incorrectly.
5. If the interface changes to use a different type of smart pointer, the client will *want* to know. They don't want to continue passing objects thinking that they're passing ownership if in reality they're sharing it. They'll especially want to know if the opposite happens.

Comment: Let us consider a case. User uses a dialog to generate a new derived item. It is put on `std::unique_ptr<DerivedItem> item`. When click 'OK' button, it is added to the container. If failed to add, go back to the dialog for an edit. Which way is more convenient? Thanks.

Comment: @user1899020 I'm sticking with my answer. It's independent of what exactly you're using `MyContainer` for. I just recommend that you allow an exception to propagate if you can't add the `Item`. It's up to the client to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the first way seriously compromises type safety – you’ve pointed that our yourself in the disadvantages. I think those concerns are overriding any advantages this method may have.

In particular, the potential error with the second method when using a derived object is caught at compile time so it’s annoying, but *safe*!

I agree about your assessment that this usage leaks implementation details but in my experience such leakage is unavoidable – I agree with sfrabbit that this is actually a detail that the user of the class needs to know about.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this as another tool in the toolbox:

```
bool Add(std::unique_ptr<Item>&& item);
```

This combines the advantages of Way 2 and Way 3.  I.e. it will only accept rvalue `unique_ptr`s (like 2), but if there is some failure in adding it to the container, it can retain ownership like 3.  Could be used something like:

```
void
foo(MyContainer& c)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Item> p = get_Item();
    try
    {
        c.Add(std::move(p));
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        log_error_wtih(*p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the same as Way 2? Can it do that: `std::unique_ptr<Item> a(new Item); Add(a);` like Way 3?